# Hypothesis testing for difference in proportions when pooled population proportion is known

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, contingency-tables

The example I use below to frame my questions is a bit contrived, but I am hoping the answer will help to clarify my understanding of more complex, related issues.

Suppose we know in advance that the proportion of men (vs women) in a large metropolitan area is 50% (e.g.- from a just-completed census or recently published demographic data).  A researcher is seeking to evaluate whether the proportion of men that smoke is different than the proportion of women that smoke in this population.

A random sample of 40 adult smokers is performed, and their gender is recorded.  Another independent random sample of 40 adult non-smokers is performed, and their gender is similarly recorded.  The results are summarized below:

[image]

Now to my thinking the test of interest would be a test of homogeneity (as opposed to a test of association or independence).  I calculated the following p-values from this data:

Z-Test of difference in proportions with continuity correction (cc):  0.0442

Lognormal Z-Test of difference in proportions with cc:  0.0433

Fisher Exact Test:  0.0435

Product Binomial Exact Test:  0.0930

Not surprisingly, the first 3 p-values or all very nearly the same.  But the last p-value that I have labelled "Product Binomial Exact Test" is more than twice as high.  I arrive at this p-value by summing the probabilities of all possible outcomes that have an equal or lower probability of occurrence compared to the observed outcome.  The probability of any specific outcome is the product of 2 independent binomials:

Probability that x of the 40 non-smokers are women, *given that 50% of the population are women*; multiplied by 
Probability that x of the 40 smokers are women, *given that 50% of the population are women*

So for the specific outcomes observed we have:

Probability that 25 of the 40 non-smokers are women, *given that 50% of the population are women* (=.0366); multiplied by

Probability that 15 of the 40 smokers are women, *given that 50% of the population are women* (=.0366)

= 0.001338

My questions are as follows:

**1)  Is the Product Binomial Exact Test (PBET) calculation I have described above the correct way to calculate the probability of the observed outcome, given that we know the true proportion of women is 50% in this population?**  *In effect, I think that I am calculating the probability of the observed outcome under a null hypothesis that the proportion of female smokers = proportion of male smokers = 50%*

**2)  Why would the other p-values all be so much lower than PBET value?**  The column totals are fixed by design, and I purposely contrived the "observed" counts so the sample marginal proportion of women came out to equal the known population marginal proportion of women (50%).  So in computing the other p-values we are still using the same proportion (50%) to calculate the test statistics.  *These tests are - as I understand it - effectively calculating the probability of the observed outcome under a null hypothesis that the proportion of female smokers = the proportion of male smokers, **but NOT that the proportion is equal to 50% or any other specific proportion.***  My thinking is that the difference is due to the fact that all these other tests are NOT conditioned on the true proportion being equal to 50%...and the next thing I was about to type feels like circular reasoning (can u guess? ...something Bayesian...?).

I hope the community does not feel I am beating a dead horse on this issue - I have posted a number of similar and related questions recently as I try to develop my intuition in this area of inferential statistics.  Thanks for your continued patience and guidance with my (very slowly) developing knowledge! It is much denser than I imagined...comments and answers from Scortchi, Jmhuber and Bjorn in particular have been extremely helpful and greatly appreciated to date :)